# How do I fix "The specified cluster could not be found." in my IBM Cloud Continuous Delivery pipeline's deploy stage?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

I have a pipeline that deploys to a IBM Cloud Kubernetes cluster in a resource group other than the default. Recently, I have started seeing errors of the form...

```
The specified cluster could not be found. If you're using resource groups, make sure that you target the correct resource group.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because of a change that was made to the IBM Cloud command line (i.e."ibmcloud ks" or "ibmcloud cs") that now requires the resource group to be set before doing a "cluster-config" command. If you are seeing this, for now you should be able to resolve it by going into your pipeline's deploy stage, selecting the correct resource group in the "Resource Group" field and then saving the stage.

We are working on an update to respond to the change in the ibmcloud command, and will release it as soon as it's finished and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your local resource group does not match the cluster's resource group:

Change the targeted resource group as follows:

```
$ ibmcloud ks clusters
Name               ID             State     Created   Workers  Location  Version       Resource Group Name   
mycluster-dev   236*******1071   normal 6 months ago    6    Washington  1.12.6_1521   My-Resource-Group

# Change the targeted resource group
$ ibmcloud target -g My-Resource-Group

$ ibmcloud ks cluster-config mycluster-dev
OK
The configuration for mycluster-dev was downloaded successfully.
Export environment variables to start using Kubernetes.
export KUBECONFIG=/home/.../.bluemix/plugins/.....yml
```